# Scala plugin for netbeans

Tags: scala, plugins, netbeans, ide

I try to run scala plugin under NetBesans 6.9.1. I install scala from arch linux repositories. Then i download netbeans-6.9.1 and scala plugin. Installed plugin. When i create scala application with hello world and try it to build i get error:

```
You must set SCALA_HOME or environment property and append "-J-Dscala.home=scalahomepath"                   
property to the end of "netbeans_default_options" in NetBeansInstallationPath/etc/netbeans.conf to point to
                    Scala installation directory.
```

How can i fix it?

I put in my netbeans.conf **J-Dscala.home=/usr/bin/scala** but it's not helpful. After that i get error: **Could not load definitions from resource scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have Arch Linux installed, but looking at [scala package contents](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/scala/) I think the proper value for SCALA_HOME is `/usr/share/scala`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to mess up with the environment variables in linux while setting up scala in netbeans then:

search for "scala-library.jar"

wherever you find it, copy that location and assign "J-Dscala.home" to that

for example

"J-Dscala.home=/home/username/project/.../scala2.8.1"

that's it.

It worked out for me
try it in your case.

Comment: Stack Overflow aims to be a *high quality* question and answer site. Whilst your answer is technically useful the use of text speak lowers the quality of your answer. I've edited it for you, but please use complete words and sentences in future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the error message helpful enough? Did you edit the netbeans.conf file?