# Scala plugin Netbeans 7.3 $SCALA_HOME

Tags: scala, netbeans-7

I'm experiencing issues with the [Netbeans Scala plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/). I get the following error when running my project:

```
> ant -f /Volumes/Z/Users/vincent/Dropbox/Programming/Scala/U4Handler run Could not load definitions from resource scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found. init: deps-jar:
> /Volumes/Z/Users/vincent/Dropbox/Programming/Scala/U4Handler/nbproject/build-impl.xml:405:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /Volumes/Z/Users/vincent/Dropbox/Programming/Scala/U4Handler/nbproject/build-impl.xml:238:
> Problem: failed to create task or type scalac Cause: The name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place. 
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

First of all, I have no idea why it runs with the argument `ant -f`, I don't use Ant in this project. Secondly, this is what I have done to fix this error:

1. Added to `-J-Dscala.home=/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec/bin`netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf, I believe this is the actual path of the scalac binary (I installed scala using brew)
2. Created `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` containing (rebooted afterwards):

> ```
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
> <key>SCALA_HOME</key>
> <string>/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec/bin</string>
> <key>PATH</key>
> <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec/bin</string>
> </dict>
> </plist>'
> ```

3. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128374/scala-plugin-for-netbeans) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631843/compilation-issue-with-scala-netbeans-plugin) already, but did not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive Googling, I found this guy who explains it all:
[Solution](http://scalaformac.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/setting-up-scala-on-mac-osx-10-8-2-the-nbscala-plugin-for-netbeans-and-shell-scripting/)